# extension "GLX" missing on display ":0", raden, 12.04 KDE

Tags: 12.04, drivers, kde, radeon, opengl

At some point my OpenGL stopped working in Kubuntu 12.04. "glxinfo" reports `Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".` I know it worked previously since I was using before, even developing for it, so there must be some update to blame. I just want to know how to fix it.

I've looked through several other questions/searches and mostly they deal with problems with Nvidia. I have a Radeon card, and I'm not using the binary drivers (I strictly use the supported drivers). Thus I'm at a loss as to what the problem is.

---

In my XOrg.0.log I find the below line, just after it finds all the Radeon stuff. Why is it attempting to use the NVidia driver (I don't have it installed).

`(EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)`

Answer (score 2):

Something must have installed the 'nvidia-common' package which enables the NVidia check. Trying to remove that package you are asked to also remove a kubuntu desktop package. This is safe since that package is just a historical remnant and not needed. Once I got this removed, I restarted and everything is fine again.